# TSQL Find If All Records In A Group Have The Same Value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that contains a field which is used for grouping and another field which holds data.  I want a good way to find any GroupColumn value where every DataColumn value contains a specific value.

**Example**

```
+-------------+------------+
| GroupColumn | DataColumn |
+-------------+------------+
| GroupA      | Data1      |
| GroupA      | Data2      |
| GroupA      | Data3      |
| GroupB      | Data1      |<---These two values are the same
| GroupB      | Data1      |<---for the same group
| GroupC      | Data1      |
| GroupC      | Data2      |
| GroupC      | Data2      |
| GroupC      | Data3      |
+-------------+------------+
```

**Desired Output**

Group B

In the example above the DataColumn changes for GroupA and GroupC, but for GroupB both values in the DataColumn are the same so I would want this result returned.

**Current Solution**

I have 2 current solutions based around the same theme, but I feel that this is something that SQL should be able to do in a easier fashion.

1. Group everything in the table, count the times GroupColumn appears and put this into a table.  Do the same, but apply a condition.  Join the 2 tables and see where the 2 counts do not match.

   ```
   SELECT GROUPCOLUMN, COUNT(*) [TOTAL] INTO #ALL
   FROM #TABLE
   GROUP BY GROUPCOLUMN

   SELECT GROUPCOLUMN, COUNT(*) [TOTAL] INTO #SOME
   FROM #TABLE
   WHERE DATACOLUMN = 'DATA1'
   GROUP BY GROUPCOLUMN

   SELECT * FROM #ALL A
   INNER JOIN #SOME S ON A.GROUPCOLUMN = S.GROUPCOLUMN
   WHERE S.TOTAL = A.TOTAL
   ```
2. Use a SUM and a CASE to check for the specific value and count everything and check in a sub-query.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM 
   (SELECT GROUPCOLUMN, SUM(CASE WHEN DATACOLUMN = 'DATA1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [VALUE], COUNT(*) [TOTAL] FROM #TABLE (NOLOCK)
   GROUP BY GROUPCOLUMN) A
   WHERE A.VALUE = A.TOTAL
   ```

Is there a better way to do this in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

Ninja

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT GROUPCOLUMN
FROM   #TABLE (NOLOCK)
GROUP  BY GROUPCOLUMN
HAVING Count(*) = Count(case when DATACOLUMN = 'DATA1' then 1 end)
```

Comment: So simple and yet so effective!  Thanks a lot @Prdp.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like you are looking for each group that has a single distinct value in `DATACOLUMN`:

```
SELECT GROUPCOLUMN
FROM #TABLE
GROUP BY GROUPCOLUMN
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DATACOLUMN) = 1
```

Note that `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` does not count `NULL` as a distinct value.

Comment: Aha! Exactly what I was looking for. I forgot about good ol' `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to compare `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT DATACOLUMN)` to do this. Like this:

```
SELECT GROUPCOLUMN
FROM #TABLE
GROUP BY GROUPCOLUMN
HAVING Count(*) = Count(DISTINCT DATACOLUMN)
```

Comment: But he is checking only for `'DATA1'`

Comment: the example sql uses that value, but the question text only says "a specific value".  Not being sure of the requirement, I would certainly prefer a more flexible and generalized solution.