# count consecutive column values with same other column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a WITH SQL statement who select user's activities from a view.

```
WITH activities AS (
    SELECT a.user_uuid as user_uuid,
           EXTRACT(WEEK FROM a.activity_at) as week_number,
           EXTRACT(DOW FROM a.activity_at) AS dow
    FROM activities_view_validated a
    WHERE a.activity_at > '2022-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND a.activity_type = 'xxx'
    GROUP BY a.user_uuid, a.activity_at
)
SELECT a.user_uuid, a.week_number, a.dow as dow
FROM activities a
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2 , 3
;
```

The output look like this (uuid's are truncated)

```
  user_uuid   | week_number | dow
--------------+-------------+-----
 000debd96628 |           4 |   2
 000debd96628 |          11 |   6
 001034f0d828 |           3 |   5
 001e8576e9a7 |          11 |   1
 001e8576e9a7 |          12 |   1
 001e8576e9a7 |          13 |   1
 0023e9905086 |          12 |   6
 0025cfcb6a1e |           1 |   3
 0025cfcb6a1e |           2 |   5
 0025cfcb6a1e |           3 |   0
 0025cfcb6a1e |           4 |   0
 0025cfcb6a1e |           6 |   0
 00277fec3a8f |           5 |   4
 002cf17fa0da |          13 |   1
 0041f6e950f8 |           5 |   6
 0041f6e950f8 |           6 |   6
 0041f6e950f8 |           7 |   6
 0041f6e950f8 |          10 |   2
 0041f6e950f8 |          10 |   6
 0041f6e950f8 |          11 |   2
 0041f6e950f8 |          13 |   2
 0050c9c16ec4 |           6 |   6
 0050c9c16ec4 |          10 |   0
 00614a48d8de |           7 |   1
 00614a48d8de |          11 |   1
 00614a48d8de |          12 |   1
 00614a48d8de |          13 |   1
 006495e46a1a |          12 |   6
```

I want to query user_uuid with their consecutive week_number count having the same day of the week (dow).

So something like that in output, for the three consecutive tuesday of activity on weeks 11, 12, 13 of 001e8576e9a7 user_uuid

```
  user_uuid   | count 
--------------+-------
 001e8576e9a7 |     3
```

Is there a solution that can handle to loop to the first one if the curent week is the last.

Comment: Please add an example of what you want the output to be. The question is confusing.

Comment: I think you should group by uuid, and check if all the dow values are the same using having expression and do count on them. Check this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298186/4381062)

Comment: With this approach i'll not count consecutives week_number values, maybe i need to prepare in a different way my data.

Comment: How can you select Tuesdays when you don't have the date or the day of the week in the data that you show?

Comment: This is data from my previsous WITH SQL statement, i'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use the difference between dense_rank and week_number as group number, which means that the group number changes if there is a gap in the data.
The user with user_uuid '00614a48d8de' was present week 7 day 1 then weeks 11,12 & 13 day 1 so we have 2 groups: 1 with count 1 and 1 with count 3.

```
;with rn as
(select
 user_uuid   , week_number , dow,
 dense_rank() over (partition by user_uuid, dow order by week_number) dr
 from activities)
select 
  user_uuid,
  dow,
  (week_number - dr ) as "group",
  count(*)
from rn
where user_uuid='00614a48d8de'
group by 
  user_uuid,
  dow,
  week_number - dr 
order by
  user_uuid,
  dow;
```

> ```
> user_uuid    | dow | group | count
> :----------- | --: | ----: | ----:
> 00614a48d8de |   1 |     6 |     1
> 00614a48d8de |   1 |     9 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48881ddfe9f835cbbfc36bf5a392ad99)*

Comment: Very clear, thank you, just discovered the dense_rank(). I want to retrieve users having a "group" count over defined thresholds so this is fine, the only downside i see will be at the end of a year when reaching the last week but just a SQL CASE to add.